# Error with dynamic procedure statement

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting the error `"Error: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement."`, but I have been checking the code for hours and I cant find the problem. Any help?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id_center =?";
$params = array(4);


// This will loop through params, and generate types. e.g. 'ss'
$types = '';                        
foreach($params as $param) {        
    if(is_int($param)) {
        $types .= 'i';              //integer
    } elseif (is_float($param)) {
        $types .= 'd';              //double
    } elseif (is_string($param)) {
        $types .= 's';              //string
    } else {
        $types .= 'b';              //blob and unknown
    }
}
array_unshift($params, $types);

print_r($params);

// Start stmt
$query = $conexion->stmt_init(); 
$query->prepare($sql);

// Bind Params
call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'),$params);

$query->execute(); 
printf("Error: %s.\n", $query->error);
```

This is what I get with `print_r($params)`:

```
Array ( [0] => i [1] => 4 )
```

Comment: We miss ur code for bind() & execute() on $conexion. Until then can't help u more.

Answer (score 0):

One `print_r(array(4))` would have help u to know where the pbm is from.

Let's walk through ur code to understand what happened :

```
- $params is defined and look like this : Array ( [0] => 4 ) 
- in foreach u'll test the value of every row in the array 
   BUT there is only one

- is_int(4) YES 
    $types = ' i'

- end foreach
- unshift_array() Will Prepend one or more elements to the beginning $params array
```

Therefore $params will looks like :

```
Array ( [0] => i [1] => 4 )
```

Comment: so $params value is Array ( [0] => i [1] => 4 ) 

then why when i use this it says that i havent supplied data?: call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'),$params);

im suppling an array of 2 elements

Comment: "Error: No data supplied for parameters in prepared statement." is all about $query->execute();  u didn't bind_param() on id_center

Comment: yes, im doing it here: call_user_func_array(array($query,'bind_param'),$params);
is like: $query->bind_param("i", "4");

Comment: A PHP function is passed by its name as a string. Any built-in or user-defined function can be used, except language constructs such as: array(), echo, empty(), eval(), exit(), isset(), list(), print or unset().
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php
u can't pass this array into call_ser_func_array in first param .